# Vertical align text in block element

Tags: html, css

I know vertical alignment is always asked about, but I don't seem to be able to find a solution for this particular example. I'd like the text centered within the element, not the element centered itself:

```css
li a {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: auto 0;
    display: block;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="">I would like this text centered vertically</a></li>
</ul>
```

Is there really no CSS property for this? I'd be willing to add a `<span>` in but I really don't want to add any more markup than that.

Comment: Is the height fixed at 100px? You could probably use the absolute positioning "hack" for vertical centering if that is the case: http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html

Answer (score 106, accepted):

According to the [CSS Flexible Box Layout Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/), you can declare the `a` element as a **flex container** (see figure) and use `align-items` to *vertically* align text along the **cross axis** (which is perpendicular to the **main axis**).

[image]

All you need to do is:

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GqBAL/651/).

Comment: The line-height will only work if the text doesn't go onto a second line. Then you'd have a couple of issues ;-)

Comment: Yes, indeed, I'd like something that ha the flexibility to be multiple lines. Thanks

Comment: Brilliant, thanks very much! I came so close to this a few hours ago and then went down a different track for some reason. Damn it. CSS3 to the rescue. Thanks!

Comment: I've been looking for CSS to do this for a long time, great solution! Is there an easy way to center the text in the horizontal direction as well? The CSS in your post seems to override the text-align property.

Comment: Adding a `ul { text-align: center; }` rule seems to work. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DXv44/1/).

Comment: @kajo I just tried it in FF 11 and it works. Does "it" refer to the fiddle or you tried this with some other code and it didn't work?

Comment: @melhosseiny I've tried fiddle I've tried again and this screenshot http://www.softwave.sk/files/firefox.png is what i've got :)

Comment: @kajo Yep, I see now that the text doesn't wrap as it should and as it once did! It could possibly be a FF bug. I'll update the answer once I figure it out.

Comment: CAREFUL! this is not cross-browser! 30-50% of your user will see it in unintended by designer way (IE)

Comment: @Jeffz I updated the answer to comply with `css3-flexbox` which is a CR spec. See [CSS Flexbox CR Test Suite Results](http://test.csswg.org/harness/results/CSS3-FLEXBOX_DEV/grouped/) for more info on browser support.

Comment: Flexbox will not work in IE or Firefox (as of Dec 2013). This is not good advice.

Comment: @superluminary I just tested this in FF 25.0.1 and it works. I don't have access to IE so I can't verify your claim, although I did address IE and would expect this to work at least in later versions. You can always use a fallback for IE if you really need to support it. Also, the OP has specifically requested CSS3 properties.

Comment: Dec 22, 2014,  chrome `v 39.0.2171.95 m`, ff `34.0` both works fine just with `display: flex; align-items: center;`, IE 8 and 9 does not work, and does not look good, better define custom styles for them.

Comment: Thanks, this saved me in a situation where I had to deal with a hundred different boxes that had custom padding/margins for centering which is a terrible decision for responsive design. This was a great override with perfect precision!

Comment: It doesn't work for IE.
It causes other issues in IE, e.g.: no wrap of text.

Comment: @Anton Just checked this in IE11. It works. Text wraps. Also, if you read the question, OP asked for a CSS3 solution. These days IE support shouldn't be assumed.

Comment: @melhosseiny
Could you share an example?

Comment: @Anton There's a jsfiddle in the answer, which you can try on IE11. If you can isolate the issue you're experiencing on a codepen or something, I can try to help debug it.

Comment: Is it just me or this answer doesnt address the main problem. They are asking for such alignment for a BLOCK , this changes to FLEX. Without addressing the original answer. Then if we ask we get duplicate question tag and redirected for this wrong answer

Answer (score 57):

You can also try

```
a {
  height:100px;
  line-height:100px;
}
```

Comment: This single line method was my first answer but if you read the first three comments you will see that the OP wants a general solution.

Comment: Also doesn't work for anything that has a dynamic height

Comment: The problem with this is having 2 or more lines. The next line will go missing.

Comment: If you have a multiline text, you can divide it in <span> tags and adjust your CSS to display them as block elements. Then, adjust line-height and padding-top of the <span> tags in the CSS to align them vertically. Unless you really need a dynamical solution, I guess it is the simpler cross-browser solution for the problem.

Answer (score 12):

```
li a {
width: 300px;
height: 100px;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
margin: auto 0;
background: red;
```

}

Comment: I am very suprised this is the first use of table-cell I have seen on this post. Supported down to ie8.

Comment: use `text-align: center;` to recover h.alignment @PeterX

Comment: this is the only answer that worked for me - above accepted flex answer doesn't seem to center horizontally in FF even in 2016

Comment: This does align the text correctly, but the problem with this - using it for a link - is that the entire "cell" is now clickable. So (from this specific code), now the user could click anywhere inside the 300x100 area and it will go to the destination, which is an issue if the expectation is to have a text link, rather than an "image" or full area link.

Answer (score 6):

`display: grid; place-content: center;`

no need margin.

```css
li a {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    display: grid;
    place-content: center;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="">I would like this text centered vertically</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try the display:inline-block and :after.Like this:

#### HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="">I would like this text centered vertically</a></li>
</ul>
```

#### CSS

```
li a {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: auto 0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: red;  
}
li a:after {
  content:"";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1px solid transparent;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Please view the [demo](http://codepen.io/airen/pen/vhlpb).

Comment: `width: 1px solid transparent;` -- did you mean border? Here's the tweak: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/asDGl

Comment: this solution doesn't support multi-line text & is therefore even less useful than the `line-height` trick

Answer (score 2):

Would using padding be OK for your needs?:  http://jsfiddle.net/sm8jy/:

```
li {
    background: red;
    text-align:center;
}
li a {
    padding: 4em 0;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: I'm affraid I require the height to be exactly 100px every time, regardless of number of lines, text-size, line-height etc. If we used 50px instead of 4em, this just adds 50px either side of the text. The height of the text is variable so the total height would never be uniform accross multiple list items.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `inline-table` alongside `table-cell` if you want to center your items vertically and horizontally. Below an example of using those display properties to make a menu:

```css
.menu {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  height: 30px; /* calc(16px + 12px * 2) */
}

.menu-container {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  height: 100%;
}

.menu-item {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-table;
  height: 100%;
}

.menu-item a {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 2px;
  padding-right: 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: initial;
}

.text-upper {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.text-bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="menu">
    <ul class="menu-container">
      <li class="menu-item text-upper text-bold"><a href="javascript:;">StackOverflow</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="javascript:;">Getting started</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="javascript:;">Tags</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

It works by setting `display: inline-table;` to all the `<li>`, and then applying `display: table-cell;` and `vertical-align: middle;` to the children `<a>`. This gives us the power of `<table>` tag without using it.

This solution is useful if you do not know the height of your element.

The compatibilty is very good (relative to [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table)), with Internet Explorer >= 8.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the general solution using just CSS, with two variations. The first centers vertically in the current line, the second centers within a block element.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>
            line one
        </li>
        <li>
            <span style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle">line two dot one
                <br />
                line two dot two</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            line three
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div style="height: 200px; line-height: 200px; border-style: solid;">
            <span style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; line-height: normal;">line two dot one
                <br />
                line two dot two</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As I understand it, vertical-align applies only to inline-block elements, e.g., `<img>`. You have to change an element's display attribute to inline-block for it to work. In the example, the line height expands to fit the span. If you want to use a containing element, such as a `<div>`, set the line-height attribute to be the same as the height. Warning, you will have to specify line-height: normal on the contained `<span>`, or it will inherit from the containing element.

Comment: `vertical-align` applies to: 1) table cells; 2) `inline` elements; 3) `inline-block` elements.

Answer (score 0):

with thanks to Vlad's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166574/vertical-align-text-in-block-element#22858771) for inspiration; tested & working on IE11, FF49, Opera40, Chrome53

```
li > a {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center; /* H align */
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

centers in all directions nicely even with text wrapping, line breaks, images, etc.

I got fancy and made a snippet

```css
li > a {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  display: table-cell;
  /*H align*/
  text-align: center;
  /*V align*/
  vertical-align: middle;
}
a.thin {
  width: 40px;
}
a.break {
  /*force text wrap, otherwise `width` is treated as `min-width` when encountering a long word*/
  word-break: break-all;
}
/*more css so you can see this easier*/

li {
  display: inline-block;
}
li > a {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 30px;
  background: aliceblue;
}
li > a:hover {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 30px;
  background: aqua;
}
```

```html
<li><a href="">My menu item</a>
</li>
<li><a href="">My menu <br> break item</a>
</li>
<li><a href="">My menu item that is really long and unweildly</a>
</li>
<li><a href="" class="thin">Good<br>Menu<br>Item</a>
</li>
<li><a href="" class="thin">Fantastically Menu Item</a>
</li>
<li><a href="" class="thin break">Fantastically Menu Item</a>
</li>
<br>
note: if using "break-all" need to also use "&lt;br>" or suffer the consequences
```

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT USE THE 4th solution from top if you are using ag-grid. It will fix the issue for aligning the element in middle but it might break the thing in ag-grid (for me i was not able to select checkbox after some row). Problem is not with the solution or ag-grid but somehow the combination is not good.

**DO NOT USE THIS SOLUTION FOR AG-GRID**

```
li a {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: auto 0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: red;  
}

li a:after {
    content:"";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1px solid transparent;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```