# Vertically align more than one line of text (menu elements)?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to vertically align the text inside an UL. Problem is that some list items have more than one line of text and therefore cannot use line-height.

**The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jaAYT/**

**Here's the result I want to achieve: http://img402.imageshack.us/img402/7979/menuor.jpg**

**Here's my HTML:**

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li> <a href="#"><span>WHAT IS TEAM X?</span></a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#"><span>COMPANY BENEFITS</span></a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#"><span>COMPANY, COMPANY DATA</span></a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#"><span>TEAM X COVERAGE</span></a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#"><span>COMPANY2 </span></a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#"><span>COMPANY3 </span></a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#"><span>LATEST CAMPAIGNS</span></a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#"><span>CONTACT</span></a> </li>
</ul>
```

**Here's the CSS:**

```
.menu {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    width: 720px;
}
.menu li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
.menu li a {
    width: 86px;
    height: 52px;
    padding: 15px 0px 15px 4px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
.menu li a:hover {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

Thank you!
Cris

Comment: How would you like to vertically align them (e.g. top, center, bottom)?

Comment: I want them on the center. I've added a photo to describe what I want: http://img402.imageshack.us/img402/7979/menuor.jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add these declarations to the `.menu li a` rule:

```
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: box;
-webkit-box-align: center;
-moz-box-align: center;
box-align: center;
```

See updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PjA6s/).

**08/14/13** See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166574/vertical-align-text-in-block-element) for current syntax.

Comment: Works beautifully! It's vertically aligned in the middle just how I needed it to. You've saved me so much time! Regarding the other comment: it just needed "text-align: center" for the text to be in the middle. Thanks again!

Comment: I checked and it only works in Chrome. Firefox, Opera and IE don't do it right? Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: It's a bit irresponsible to suggest Flexbox without pointing out the browser support: http://caniuse.com/flexbox (*why am I saying this?* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342755/how-to-vertically-center-more-than-one-line-of-text-works-only-on-chrome)

Comment: @user649482 It's not supported in IE or Opera. It doesn't work in FF because you have a `float: left;` declaration. Might be a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=660699) in FF. @thirtydot If a question has a CSS3 tag, it should be ok to answer it without mentioning CSS3 support issues unless the OP asks about it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/codingfreak/jaAYT/9/)

Comment: I think he meant the text inside has to be alligned horizontally so that that seem to be on the same line/row!

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean; I want the text inside to be aligned vertically sorry for the confusion. Here's an image of what I want: http://img402.imageshack.us/img402/7979/menuor.jpg

Answer (score 1):

It's not the prettiest thing to do and it will not work if the links are dynamically generated, but you could add special classes to those spans with one or two lines only and then add some `padding` at the top to center the text.

```
.oneLine {display:block; padding-top:1.25em;}
.twoLines {display:block; padding-top:.75em;}

<ul class="menu">
    <li> <a href="#"><span class="twoLines">WHAT IS TEAM X?</span></a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#"><span class="twoLines">COMPANY BENEFITS</span></a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#"><span>COMPANY, COMPANY DATA</span></a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#"><span>TEAM CYCAD COVERAGE</span></a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#"><span class="oneLine">COMPANY2 </span></a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#"><span class="oneLine">COMPANY3 </span></a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#"><span class="twoLines">LATEST CAMPAIGNS</span></a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#"><span class="oneLine">CONTACT</span></a> </li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/4MWTj/