# How to vertically center more than one line of text (works only on chrome)?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I got my answer from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323587/vertically-align-more-than-one-line-of-text-menu-elements) but found out today that the solution only works in Chrome. Opera, IE & Firefox puts the menu links (they are dynamically generated by WP) at the top. I've been trying to fix this for the past hour but to no avail...

Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/PjA6s/

If the CSS solution is complex could this be done with jQuery? Could you please direct me to a tutorial on how to achieve this (css, jquery)?

Thanks!

Comment: What is it that you want to do, exactly?  It's not at all clear from your question.

Comment: If what you want is for the text in the `<a>` tags to end up so that the short, single-line entries are vertically centered with respect to the other ones, well, that looks pretty bad to me anyway :-)  It's much nicer when they're aligned at the top.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. Here's what I want to achieve http://img402.imageshack.us/img402/7979/menuor.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The css3 method described in the other solution is ideal, but you could use the table-cell method. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/h7Htk/

Comment: For which the browser support is much better than Flexbox: http://caniuse.com/css-table