# How to make text-align:right, display:box and box-align:center work together for short text?

Tags: text, css, centering, text-align

I was wondering why short text does not seem to be affected by the text-align property once the following CSS3 technique for centering the text is applied (see the answer):

[Vertical align text in block element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166574/vertical-align-text-in-block-element)

Here is the JSFiddle of that example with an added text-align:right property: http://jsfiddle.net/GqBAL/187/
(notice that here the text get's aligned properly because it is long)

But once the text is short, it doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/GqBAL/198/
Is there some kind of "reason" for that? What am I missing? I'd like to use the technique but for any text length, not just longer ones. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about reason (most likely it has something to do with displaying content as a box). But there is a solution: use [`box-pack` property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-pack.asp). Adding

```
-webkit-box-pack: end;
-moz-box-pack: end;
```

to your example [did the trick](http://jsfiddle.net/GqBAL/202/).

Comment: ...but now longer text that breaks will not be aligned to the right anymore :( See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GqBAL/225/) Any ideas?

Comment: Ah, it just misses the "text-align: right"...then it [works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/GqBAL/227/)! Thanks again!